# when exactly we get error ENETUNREACH with connect function call in linux

Tags: linux, sockets

my system, which is a client tries to connect to (authentication) server. So route to server should be available and we try to connect to
server for authenticating ports. We have the startup configuration file that has the configuration to learn the route dynamically to server
and configuration to authenticate ports by connecting to server.

startup configuration is used on reboot.

when I reboot system with connect function being called on reboot it returns error ENETUNREACH SOMETIMES, initially I thought it is because
route to server is not available yet when the connect gets called, so to reproduce it ALWAYS I removed the configuration part that
learns the route to server, to my surprise it again is reproducible only sometimes. When not reproduced (connect returned success)
I tried configuring the route to server and communication started with the server

so when exactly is the error ENETUNREACH returned by connect function?
why does connect return success when no route to server is available?

socket type is SOCK_DGRAM
setsockopt SO_REUSEADDR & SO_REUSEPORT is set to 1

any other pointers to debug this issue will be helpful.

Comment: ENETUNREACH means no route was found.

Comment: @stark That's not correct. That would return ENOROUTETOHOST. ENETUNREACH means that no interface was found connected to a route that *was* found.

Answer (score 0):

I could find out the reason for error ENETUNREACH

this happens because neither default route nor route to destination is
available at the time of connect call

with any one of this available connect call succeeds

Answer (score -3):

Why you are using connect call for SOCK_DGRAM (UDP?) kind of sockets? Seems to be your destination is not ready hence you are getting ENETUNREACH, if its not reachable then you might have got ENETDOWN

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: And it isn't correct. UDP connect doesn't care whether the destination is ready or not. Answer seems to be mere guesswork.

Comment: The only thing `connect()` does on a UDP socket is set a default-destination to be used for later `send()` (not `sendto()`) calls on that UDP socket... and it installs a filter so that incoming UDP packets will only be `recv()`'d by that socket if they come from the specified IP-address-and-port.