# List of possible errno codes for TCP socket connections on Linux for recv/send?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, errno

Is there a complete list of errno values that can be returned after `recv` and `send`, respectively, for TCP connections on Linux (`connect` has succeeded) that are caused by pure network errors?

I'm trying to differentiate between:

- programming errors/memory failures like `EBADF`, `EFAULT`, `EINVAL`, `ENOMEM` etc.,
- special errors like `EWOULDBLOCK`, `EINTR`, and
- the case when the TCP connection has been terminated for any reason.

So far, for the case of the TCP connection has terminated for some reason, I have e.g. noticed that `recv` can result in `ECONNRESET`, `EHOSTUNREACH`, `ETIMEDOUT` and `ENETUNREACH` and that `send` can result in `EPIPE`, `ECONNRESET`, `EHOSTUNREACH`, `ETIMEDOUT`. Are there any others I need to handle?

I've tried to read the man pages for `recv(2)`, `send(2)`, `tcp(7)`, `ip(7)`, `socket(7)` but have so far not yet been able to find any documentation for why the `ENETUNREACH` error code being returned. Is this a documentation bug?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67497921/when-exactly-we-get-error-enetunreach-with-connect-function-call-in-linux#comment119425147_67497921

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you'll find a detailed exhaustive list that documents exactly why/when each errno can be generated in every possible case. The linux network stack is complicated and errors can be generated by several different layers/modules. Also, details could even change over time as kernel code gets refactored. I think the best you can do is to handle certain well-known errnos and have a fallback case that handles all the rest.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The `ENETUNREACH` error is documented for the `connect(2)` call, but I can't see it documented anywhere for the `recv(2)` call, even though I get it there.